# Setting timer interval based on function execution time

Tags: c#, timer

How to set my timer to interval based on the amount of execution time of function.

```
int main()
{
Timer t=new Timer();
t.start();
myfunc();
t.stop();
long elapsed=stop-start;
Need to set timer to this interval everytime instead of fixed interval.
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? What's the why?

Comment: Need to call my function again and again and instead of providing fixed interval once why not just set interval based on the amount of execution time my function takes. Moreover my function retrieves records from database that is continuously getting updates so the execution time is going to vary with time....

Comment: Why not just run the tasks in series asynchronously? No timer needed.

Comment: Another thought - would a fixed interval between executions solve your problem?

Comment: solves the problem but not the requirement :D ...

Comment: The "requirement" seems to "fudge" the problem rather than solve it. Shouldn't the requirement change?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is using [StopWatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) that provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time. Some thing like this:

```
// Create new stopwatch
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something
myfunc();

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();

// Write result
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Myclass
{
private static Timer newTimer;

static void main()
{
newTimer=new Timer(timercallback,null,0,10000);
}

private static timercallback(Object o)
{
Stopwatch sw=new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
myfunction();
sw.Stop();
newTimer.change(0,sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
GC.Collect();
```

//This will set the timer interval based on the function execution time.
    }